# How subtract in assembly x86?

Tags: assembly

I tried this code to substract num2 from num2.Can any one tell me how to fix?

```
.minus:
                mov eax, [num1]
                sub eax, 0
                mov ebx, [num2]
                sub ebx, 0
                sub eax, ebx
                sub eax, 0
                mov [num3], eax
                jmp .resultat
```

I was expecting to substract num2 from num2.

Comment: What do you expect `sub eax, 0` to do?

Comment: Subtracting `num2` from `num2` will always be `0` (unless you use `SBB`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised to see your question today considering the answer I provided for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77576999/adding-2-numbers-in-assembly-x86).

You did not apply the correct conversions (as you were told already):

- From character to number, **subtract 48** which you can write as `sub eax,'0'`.
- From number to character, **add 48** which you can write as `add eax,'0'`.

> I was expecting to substract num2 from num2

If you truly mean to subtract num**2** from num**2**, then don't bother writing code to calculate it. Just store a '0' character in the result:

```
mov  dword [num3], '0'
```

If on the other hand the code snippet shows what you would like to calculate, then correct it like:

```
movzx eax, byte [num1]
sub   eax, '0'
movzx ebx, byte [num2]
sub   ebx, '0'
sub   eax, ebx
add   eax, '0'
mov   [num3], eax
```

eg. num1 == '8', num2 == '5' ---> num3 == '3'
Don't expect it to work if num2 is greater than num1!

Comment: The only difference from OP's code in their last question is `sub` instead of `add` [Adding 2 numbers in assembly x86](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77576999).  The problem and solution are exactly the same so it's a duplicate.  (Or the math part of the solution is inverted if you're optimizing `x-'0' - (y-'0') + '0'` into `(x-y) + '0'` vs. with addition `x+y - '0'` to correct for doubling the offset between integer digits and their ASCII codes. The movzx part is the same, and the fundamental problem of `0` vs. `'0'` is the same.) Add/sub of single-digit numbers has also been asked&answered tons